# Array in HTML to use in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Can I use something like that: `<select id="data[select]">` and get the value with jquery like that: `$("#data[select]").val();`?

Comment: You might be able to do it if you escape the `[]`. But as already said, these characters are not valid in IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Why do you need to do this anyway? I'm pretty sure CSS IDs only support `A-Z`, `123...`, and `- , _`.

What are you trying to accomplish by setting you ID like that? You can, however, get the element like this: `$("[id='data[select]']")`

Comment: @NeXXeuS: to submit values in registration page, I have to do many `$("#id_name").val();` to make it.

Comment: @NeXXeuS: Because `[]` are special characters for Sizzel (the selector engine). To escape them inside a JavaScript string, you need two backslashes (similar to when you want to escape special regular expression characters using a string and `RegExp`). Also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Source [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/types.html#type-name): ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('select[id="data[select]"]').val()
```

anyway it would be best to change the name of ID

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/qEFRA/)